# Can an IEventHandler return anything other than null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, orchardcms

Can I have something like `List<T>` as the return type of an `IEventHandler`?

I want to implement an event handler interface like this:

```
public interface IMyEventHandler: IEventHandler
{
    public List<MyType> Event (Context context)
}
```

When I call the method `Event`, it returns the list successfully. But I am not receiving the list at the caller method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general `EventHandlers` are void, because, C#'s paradigm says a return value would have not a well-defined meaning if you use subscribers to the event.

For example, a button click, would be able to return a bool, indicating success (or handled, or... etc.)

But when you have multiple subscribers to the event, it might become unclear, and a little vague on where to deliver the result.

Therefor, a little hack which you often see, is to pass, in this case your list, as an argument of the event.

Your event handlers can receive this list, in the form of an event argument, and add items to it. These items are then also available to other subscribers if the event bubbles upwards.

---

So the bottom line: don't return values from event handlers. Instead, if you absolutely must: pass an argument and do the mutations there. But, it still is a bit of a code smell so I would look for other options.